# data[i++] = data[i++] * 2 result surprised me

Tags: java, javascript

I just declare the data array

```
data = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},  i = 1;  
data[i++] = data[i++] * 2;
```

I test in Java and Javascript, the results both are

```
{0, 4, 2, 3, 4}
```

it's too strange to me, I think at first

```
data[i++] * 2, data[1] * 2 = 2,
```

then `i` becomes `2`, then `data[2] = 2` and `i` become `3`. So result should be `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}`.

Could someone know the reason of this result?

Comment: I removed your [tag:c] and [tag:c++] tags as they appear irrelevant. If your question is actually about one of those languages, please explain why in your question.

Comment: my expected result is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, not {0, 4, 2, 3, 4}

Comment: This question helps others to think in lot different way.. but  ur expectation is not clear sorry

Comment: Are you sure your expected result is {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}? Isn't that the input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1

> If the left-hand operand is an array access expression (§15.13),
>   possibly enclosed in one or more pairs of parentheses, then:
>
> - First, the array reference subexpression of the left-hand operand
>     array access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes
>     abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the
>     same reason; the index subexpression (of the left-hand operand array
>     access expression) and the right-hand operand are not evaluated and no
>     assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the index subexpression of the left-hand operand array
>     access expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly,
>     then the assignment expression completes abruptly for the same reason
>     and the right-hand operand is not evaluated and no assignment occurs.
> - Otherwise, the right-hand operand is evaluated. If this evaluation
>     completes abruptly, then the assignment expression completes abruptly
>     for the same reason and no assignment occurs.

In other words, the array index on the left hand side MUST be evaluated before the right hand side, to conform to the Java Language Specification.

This means that you'll be assigning into `data[1]`, and the value that you assign will be `data[2] * 2`.

If you're asking about Javascript though, all I can suggest is that the makers of Javascript wanted to make the result match the result from Java.

Comment: Good Point, array index one left hand side MUST be evaluated before the right hand side.

Comment: Well done for spotting the true source of confusion - order of evaluation. Although your answer is a little light on JavaScript citations.

Comment: Yes, but in effect, you asked two questions - "why does this happen in Java" and "why does this happen in Javascript".  I know the answer to only one of those questions.  Maybe a Javascript expert can answer the second one.

Comment: Sorry, I mean "OP asked two questions", not you @Duncan.

Answer (score 4):

it is an *autoincrement*, *postincrement* in it (i.e the current value of a variable is used but after using it , it's value automatically gets incremented for the next use).

in the first `data[i++]` it uses the value of i (which is 1) and then increases it, hence in the second `data[i++]` i is 2

Hence the equation becomes `data[1]=data[2]*2`

Comment: I've just meant to write it:) so basically he should do:
`data[i++]=data[i]*2;`

Comment: I know autoincrement, postincrement, I don't know why it evaluated from left hand to right hand.

Answer (score 3):

hope it does make sense

```
data[i++] = data[i++] * 2;
```

step1:-

```
 data[i++] -> data[1]//because i is under post increment
```

step2:-

```
 data[i++] * 2->data[2]*2-> 2*2 ->4 // now i is 2
```

step3:-

```
data[1] = 4;//interpreter interprets  left to right
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, an assignment of the form `a[x] = y;` is [evaluated left-to-right](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.1). That is, `x` is evaluated before `y`. The [same is true for JavaScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3ks45k7%28v=vs.94%29.aspx).

Also, the post-increment operator `x++` changes the value of `x` **after** is has been used.

Combine these two facts with a visual explanation (below) and it should all make sense:

```
i = 1;

data[i++] = data[i++] * 2;
     ^           ^
     |           |
     1           2

System.out.println(i); // would display '3'
```

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty simple... (Post Increment Does the Trick)

The value of **i++** in righthand side is changed to 2 since it has been **Post-incremented** in left hand side

```
data[i++]=data[i++]*2
```

which expands as follows:

```
data[1]=data[2]*2
data[1]=2*2;
```

hence

```
data=[0,4,2,3,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

***Javascript***

```
data[i++] = data[i++] * 2; // i === 1
data[1] = data[i++] * 2; // i === 2
data[1] = data[2]*2; // i === 3
```

The ++ operator increments the variable and then returns (is evaluated to) the original value.

One simple example for it is:

```
var x = 0;
console.log(x + (x++) + x) // 1
```

The first and second x are evaluated to 0, while the third is 1 (because it has been incremented)

Answer (score 0):

As other people have said:
data[1] = data[2]*2 and once that expression is processed i==3. However, this means that what we have next is data[3] = data[4]*2 which should be 16. So your output does not make sense.